# Does Google Webmaster Tools show nofollow links in 'Links to your site'?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

We have made some links nofollow in recent weeks, but they are still showing up in Google Webmaster Tools. Does GWT ignore these links? Will they vanish as the index is updated, or do even nofollow links show up here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are backlinks shown in GWT dofollow or nofollow?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102377/are-backlinks-shown-in-gwt-dofollow-or-nofollow)

Comment: Older questions would be the canonical of newer questions (not the other way around), so lets leave them open, but reference them instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes, GWT shows all links, followed and nofollowed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Google Webmaster shows all the links whether it's dofollow or nofollow. But it does not pass link juice from a nofollow backlink. I am also doing SEO for a company and when I look at their backlinks in Google Webmaster tool I see lots of Nofollow links that are pointing to them.

Answer (score 0):

No! Google Webmaster Tool only shows all the links pointing to your website but not showing all the do follow and no follow attributes..

Comment: Have you got anything to corroborate this? The other answer says Yes.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be answering the main question or is at best confusing? "No!" would seem to be answering the secondary question, "Does GWT ignore these links?"? "only shows all the links" - If it's showing "all the links", it's showing "all the links"; why "only"? "not showing all the do follow and no follow attributes" - correct, the _attributes_ are not shown - you cannot differentiate between the "dofollow" and "nofollow" links shown in the report.

Comment: (But a "nofollow" link is not necessarily determined by the `rel="nofollow"` _attribute_, it might be considered "nofollow" because it is using a redirect script that is blocked by `robots.txt`.)