# Are backlinks shown in GWT dofollow or nofollow?

Tags: google-search-console

Are links shown in the Google Search Console (formerly Google Webmaster Tools) "Links to your site" report, dofollow or both dofollow and nofollow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The links shown in the "Links to your site" report in Google Search Console (formerly Google Webmaster Tools) shows both dofollow and nofollow links (but it's not possible to distinguish between them).

From the following [Google+ thread](https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/gEBvDvXmvux) by [John Mueller](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/711/john-mueller) (Google employee and user on this site):

> **Yehoshua Coren** (30 Jul 2012)
>   +John Mueller I'm curious why the links that GWT shows include nofollow links.  Your thoughts?  Does it make sense to note that somehow?
>
> **John Mueller**
>   +Yehoshua Coren we show them there because to users, those links can be quite useful regardless. For example, if you have an advertisement on a website, that link - even with a rel=nofollow - can be an important source of users for your website.

Also, in this [Google+ thread regarding Disavowed links](https://plus.google.com/+BillHartzerTX/posts/TFay7cR1Tzs):

> **John Mueller** (3 Jul 2014)
>   Disavowed links are generally treated similarly to nofollow links, and we show those in Webmaster Tools as well (since nofollow links can still be useful to bring traffic to your website).

Comment: I ask one question in official hangout, I asked, "if Googlebot simply don't follow those links as you said many times then why I see those links in my search console", and they said we generally don't pass the any juicy value to nofollow link , but **we still crawl them**, and hence we display it on your search console.

Comment: Mueller answers isnt helpfull on SEO topics,he talk vaguely always.